# Как разделить трафик поровну на собственном VPN сервере?

Tags: linux, openvpn, wireguard, tc

Поднимаю свой VPN сервер. Как разделить трафик между несколькими людьми поровну? т.е. чтобы если кто то откроет видео у остальных не было потерь скорости. Подойдет инструкция как и для OpenVPN так и для Wireguard.

Comment: Я немного погуглил и нашел [это](https://serverfault.com/a/780233). Но придется доработать решение. То есть пишется скрипт, который обрабатывает события клиент подключился/отключился. Если у вас скорость 100, значит для 1 клиента ставите лимит 100. Когда присоединился второй - 100/2 = 50 ставите обоим.

Comment: я бы прикрутил FQ_CoDel для начала.